# How to get Json response from PHP which have Object and Array and Json array present inside Json Object

Tags: php, json

Hi I want JSON response in below format using PHP.

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "results": [    
      {
        "id": "123",
        "fields": {
          "trailText": "SomeText",
          "thumbnail": "URL"
        },
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": "profile/amy-walker",
            "type": "contributor",
        ]
      }
  ]
  }
}
```

My PHP Code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $temp_array[$num_rows]['id']= $row["id"];
    //Some more code
}
echo $post = json_encode(array('response'=>$myObj,$temp_array));
```

But I got response like this

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": "ok"
    },
    "results": [    
      {
        "id": "123",
        "fields": {
          "trailText": "SomeText",
          "thumbnail": "URL"
        },
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": "profile/amy-walker",
            "type": "contributor",
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

I want my array should be bound inside **response**.

`$myObj` is

```
object(stdClass)#4 (8) { 
    ["status"]=> string(2) "ok" 
    ["userTier"]=> string(9) "developer" 
    ["total"]=> int(8282) 
    ["startIndex"]=> int(1) 
    ["pageSize"]=> int(12) 
    ["currentPage"]=> int(1) 
    ["pages"]=> int(8282) 
    ["orderBy"]=> string(6) "newest" 
}
```

Comment: You could try `json_encode(array('response'=>array($myObj,$temp_array)))` to group together the last bits of data (i.e. add an extra `array()` in)

Comment: show us the value of `$myObj` by doing `var_dump($myObj);`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If `json_encode` produces a different output, then your input data is in the wrong format

Comment: @Nico Yes i have some issue with my end Nigel code worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment regarding `$myObj` data. It seems @Nigel Ren code will work for you with a small modification.

do like this:

```
$result = array($myObj->status,$temp_array);

echo $post = json_encode(array('response'=>$result));
```